# How to pass command line argument to docker run and print it?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

I created a .Net core 2.1 console application with docker (linux) support. Here is the system generated `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyApp/MyApp.fsproj MyApp/
RUN dotnet restore MyApp/MyApp.fsproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyApp
RUN dotnet build MyApp.fsproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyApp.fsproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

The console program just prints out the argument. (`Console.WriteLine("The args are {0}", args);`)

However, `docker run MyApp:dev` doesn't print anything. And `docker run MyApp:dev ABC` got the following error.

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"ABC\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

I tried `docker run -it MyApp:dev dotnet /app/MyApp.dll ABC` and it got the error of

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

Running `docker run -it MyApp:dev dotnet` shows the Usage of `dotnet`.

```
PS C:\Temp> docker run -it MyApp:dev dotnet

Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]

Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET Core information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.
```

I tried `docker run -it MyApp:dev bash` and found the dirctory `/app` is empty. `find . -name MyApp.dll` cannot find anything?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like what you're doing should work. I just made a repo here:

https://github.com/rquackenbush/DotNetCoreArgs

After building:

```
docker build .
```

I was able to run:

```
docker run <imageid> ABC
```

And I got:

```
Hello World!
There are 1 args.
  ABC
```

Comment: I tried `docker run -it dotnet /app/MyApp.dll ABC` and it got teh error of `"Unable to find image 'dotnet:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for dotnet, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'."` Should the image be specified in the command line?

Comment: Apologies - I left off the image name to run

Comment: No problem, I tried it with the image name and got the error of `Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409`

Comment: Ahh - to make sure that `dotnet` doesn't try to use the arguments you're passing for its own needs, you have to add `--`

Comment: I got the same dotnet SDK error after added `--`. I tried it in both powershell and cmd.

Comment: Try moving the -- to directly after `dotnet`

Comment: `docker run -it crawlers:dev dotnet` shows the usage of `dotnet`. It seems the path to `MyApp` is not correct.

Comment: I went back and built a repro, and what you're doing seems to work in my environment. I'm using Docker Community Edition version 18.06.0-ce on Windows 10 and was able to do this from `cmd`.

Comment: I created the console project first and then added docker support. Not sure if it will create a different docker file. My console project is in f#, this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177822/discussion-between-rqdq-and-ca9163d9).